# Paid app to Free app with Inapp purchase

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, in-app-purchase, appstore-approval

I have my paid app in appstore now I am converting it to a free app with inapp purchase. and i want to give the data free for the user's who purchased my Version 1.0. At this point I am facing a problem. If the user buys my paid app and if he deletes the app after sometime before I release my update what should I do in this case I want to give the data for free for the user's who deleted the app also. I have two questions here

1) Will my app gets approved even If I don't give the data for free for the users who deleted the application and doesn't have any backup of my app ?

2) If it is possible to give the data for free for the user's who deleted the app please tell me the way how to do it?

Comment: Hi Mudassir,You can not do anything if the user delete the app from device and install your latest in app purchase version. If your application is interacting with your server and storing information about the user who purchased the app, means it depend of your app functionality. If your app is social networking app  any  login/ registration is there inside your app and that  registration of user you are storing on your server then you can allow free access of your app based on the  registration mail id of that user.

Comment: Secondly, if you have any database sqllite inside your application then you can allow free access of your users based on that database.What you can do is on your latest release change the name of hat database and when your application start then you can check if previously database exist already if yes that means that is old user and you can allow that user free access of your content.Plese note that if user delete the app before installing your latest version then in that case we can not do anything and another a case is that

Comment: if user install his app on another iPad then in that case also we can not do anything. Now answer to your questions:- 1. yes your app gets approved by apple whether or not you are giving content free to old user apple did not care of that. 2. we can not do anything if user delete the app before installing your latest version of app until and unless  your app has some interaction with your server.Let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: @:Sandeep Dhama: Hi Sandeep, can you please post your comments as an answer, so that I can accept it..? :)

Comment: hi Mudassir i have  post my comment as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not do anything if the user delete the app from device and install your latest in app purchase version. If your application is interacting with your server and storing information about the user who purchased the app, means it depend of your app functionality. If your app is social networking app any login/ registration is there inside your app and that registration of user you are storing on your server then you can allow free access of your app based on the registration mail id of that user.

Secondly, if you have any database sqllite inside your application then you can allow free access of your users based on that database.What you can do is on your latest release change the name of hat database and when your application start then you can check if previously database exist already if yes that means that is old user and you can allow that user free access of your content.Plese note that if user delete the app before installing your latest version then in that case we can not do anything and another a case is that

if user install his app on another iPad then in that case also we can not do anything. Now answer to your questions:- 1. yes your app gets approved by apple whether or not you are giving content free to old user apple did not care of that. 2. we can not do anything if user delete the app before installing your latest version of app until and unless your app has some interaction with your server.Let me know if you have any other questions

Comment: To support users that do delete your database and don't have a backup, you can issue promo codes to them on a case-by-case basis if there aren't many of them.

Comment: This answer is out-of-date as of iOS 7. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19390810/change-paid-app-to-free-but-know-if-user-previously-purchased-it