# Change paid app to free but know if user previously purchased it

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I am considering changing my paid `iOS` app to be free, making it `ad based`, and having an `in-app purchase` option to remove the ads.

This sounds like a good idea if I was just launching the app, but we have over 30k paid downloads, and I don't want those users to ever see the ads when they update to the new version which is free.

**Do I have any options here?**

Comment: Are you storing anything in user defaults / keychain ?

Comment: Yes, storing if they are using metric or not.

Comment: I would not switch to free, 30k is good :-)

Answer (score 69):

As of iOS 7, this can be done using proper receipt validation. Under iOS 7 you can obtain a receipt for the purchased app. Part of the data in the receipt includes information about the original purchase version of the app by the user. You can look at that version and if it is from before the release of your update to free with IAP, you can choose to give the user the full functionality without the user needing to purchase the upgrade again.

Of course if you wish your updated app to work under iOS 6, this is not an option.

See the [Receipt Validation Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Introduction.html) for details on receipt validation.

Comment: This sounds like a great idea, but I need to support back to iOS5.

Comment: I agree with Matthias. Assume the vast majority of *new* revenue will come from iOS7 and just give away features/etc to iOS6 and below. Everything will be much simpler this way. Nic, you should accept rmaddy's answer.

Comment: Or you could remove "pro" features from older systems with a message to update their systems. Also you'll have less features to test in the older systems.

Comment: Does the receipt contain information about whether the app was downloaded with a promo code when it was paid? Been googling for a while but I can't seem to find an answer to this.

Comment: how can i get original purchase date of appstore purchase not in-app purchase?

Answer (score 3):

try fetch all receipt & analyse them by following data:

```
"expires_date" = "2017-09-24 11:25:19 Etc/GMT";
"original_purchase_date" = "2017-09-24 11:20:21 Etc/GMT";
"product_id" = "com.yourapp.service";
```

**1. Get all user's receipts from the app store**

```
+ (NSArray*)all_receipts{
    // Load the receipt from the app bundle.
    NSURL *receiptURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle]appStoreReceiptURL];
    NSData *receipt = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:receiptURL];
    if(!receipt){
        //no receipts yet...
        return nil;     
    }

    NSError *error;
    NSDictionary *requestContents = @{@"receipt-data": [receipt base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0],
                                      @"password":YOUR_SECRED_SHARED};
    NSData *requestData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:requestContents
                                                          options:0
                                                            error:&error];
    if (!requestData) {
        return [NSArray array];
    }

    // Create a POST request with the receipt data.
    //get current qa / production url
    BOOL sandbox = [[receiptURL lastPathComponent]isEqualToString:@"sandboxReceipt"];
    NSURL *storeURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt"];
    if (sandbox) {
        storeURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt"];
    }
    NSDictionary *jsonResponse = [LTServer postUrl:storeURL.absoluteString attach:requestContents];
    NSLog(@"jsonResponse %@",jsonResponse);
    if(!jsonResponse){
        return [NSArray array];
    }
    NSArray *receipts_data = jsonResponse[@"latest_receipt_info"];
    return [receipts_data mutableCopy];
}
```

**2. Each receipt will contain a dictionary:**

```
    "expires_date" = "2017-09-24 11:25:19 Etc/GMT";
    "expires_date_ms" = 1506252319000;
    "expires_date_pst" = "2017-09-24 04:25:19 America/Los_Angeles";
    "is_trial_period" = true;
    "original_purchase_date" = "2017-09-24 11:20:21 Etc/GMT";
    "original_purchase_date_ms" = 1506252021000;
    "original_purchase_date_pst" = "2017-09-24 04:20:21 America/Los_Angeles";
    "original_transaction_id" = 1000000339209266;
    "product_id" = "com.yourapp.service";
    "purchase_date" = "2017-09-24 11:20:19 Etc/GMT";
    "purchase_date_ms" = 1506252419000;
    "purchase_date_pst" = "2016-11-27 04:20:19 America/Los_Angeles";
    quantity = 1;
    "transaction_id" = 1000000337203266;
    "web_order_line_item_id" = 1000000030161297;
```

Comment: This receipt is for in-app purchase or app purchase? i want to get appstore purchase receipt not in-app purchase. How can i get it? Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

If your current app has any data in user defaults or the keychain then that can be the indicator. When the app is first opened (in your new version) run a bit of code which:

1. Checks for the data in defaults / keychain
2. If found, enable the paid content / disable the ads
3. Migrate that data to a new key (so you don't upgrade again / give away free stuff)

Comment: Yeah, I am thinking it won't work. Because some users might not upgrade for a while, then finally upgrade to the second "free" version which would break the scenario.

Comment: How so? The point is that anyone using the old app will have the original key. Anyone who has been upgraded or installed the new version will have the new key.

Comment: Say that had the app a year ago, and have deleted it since, and they also got a new iPhone. They go to their "Purchased" list and re-download my app since they bought it before. I don't see a way I can know that they paid for it.

Comment: @NicHubbard you have to validate receipt in that case. I was thinking the same. I do all steps Wain suggested but if they all failed I do receipt validation only once, and based on it's result I set keychain data.

Comment: @applefreak if the steps fail, which they would with all new installs, doesn't that mean there would be a receipt validation with every NEW install?  That is, if it's the first time a user is installing the app, step 1 and 2 will fail.  At what point, is there ever a point, when we wouldn't have to do a receipt validation?

Answer (score -1):

Woudnt it be easier to just offer a free inanpp purchase at launch on the paid app. A button saying something like "Upgrade". And then switch that free inapp to paid on the next update?

Comment: This would be a problem for people who have already purchased the app, but deleted it. If they download it again in a few months and so missed the app version with the 'upgrade' button. They would simply install the update and it would be the free version which of course contains ads.

Answer (score -2):

In itunes connect you can generate promotion codes for in app purchases. You may create an IAP item for premium features, and give it as a promotion to the purchasers manually. Not an automatic solution though, it might save you from some headache.

Comment: On iTunesConnect (now called AppstoreConnect) you are (very) limited to 100 promos codes by app update, and each promo code will be "alive" 28 days after having created it. With 30k app sold, I don't think this is a realistic solution...

Answer (score -4):

The only option is to release two updates. The first will write a value to NSUserDefaults identifying them as a purchaser. The second update is your ad-supported version which can read this purchaser-identifying value and hide the ads.

Comment: Yeah, but this wouldn't work if someone has purchased in the past and then re-downloads the app in the future after I release the free version.

Comment: @NicHubbard, that is effectively impossible to deal with automatically. You would need to offer an upgrade path for those users which used a custom URL scheme or something like that.

Comment: @NicHubbard Does the current version write anything to NSUserDefaults, the keychain, or the Documents directory? You could check for those in the free version **before** the app writes anything to persistent storage.

Comment: @neilco Yes it does. My issue is what if a user bought my app and has since deleted it. If they choose to download it again, and perhaps have a new phone, they wouldn't have those keys written to NSUserDefaults.

Comment: @NicHubbard Those are the edge cases who, unfortunately, are going to miss out.

Answer (score -5):

Not really, no. Best you can do is publish an update while it's still a paid app that writes some value to NSUserDefaults (or a file in the app data directory, doesn't matter which) that indicates it was purchased. Wait a week or however long you want, then publish an update that removes that code, timed to be released the same day the price changes to free.