# Adding Ads to App - Accounting For Past Customers

Tags: ios, iad

I'm about to implement ads into an app that was previously a paid app. I wouldn't want any of my past customers who purchased the app to have to see ads. Is there a way programmatically that I can check to see if they already have the app installed, and if they do, exclude them from the ads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an interesting problem. I'd release a version of the app that is just like the version in the field and have those users write out a value to a plist. Wait a month. Then release the ad version. This isn't perfect, if a paid customer deletes the app and re-installs it they see the ads.

Will the new version have a paid upgrade to eliminate ads? If so, I think there is a way to gift the paid version. However I also believe that that is limited to a small number of installs.

And of course the real answer is here: [Change paid app to free but know if user previously purchased it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19390810/change-paid-app-to-free-but-know-if-user-previously-purchased-it)

That is iOS7 only though, but it is the best way.

Comment: That's a great idea and I'll probably go with that. Thanks!