# Showing Upgrade Button to Only New Users in iOS Application

Tags: ios, app-store

I have an app on the app store. It is a fixed price app. I want to remove the fix pricing and add the In-App purchase model. For that I need to provide all the existing features to my existing customers but provide a subset of features for the new customers. New customers will get the app for free but will less features. They will use the upgrade button to get all the features.

What can I do to make sure that the existing customers do not pay for the upgrade?

Is receipt validation the way to go?

Comment: Why not release a Lite or Free version of your current app instead?

Comment: Working with this type of purchasing model always leads to application hacking, as you might know there's a Jailbroken tweak named LocalAPStore that can fake receipts, so it's a no-go for receipts at the moment, what big companies have done for this is creating their own user purchases platforms if they're selling in the app, or the simpler way, lite or complete edition.

Comment: @JoelHernandez My app is not of type that user will go downloading illegal version of it. It is app about flower gardening.

Comment: There are many questions with answers to this. A good answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19390810/558933

Comment: @RoboticCat Looks like receipt validation is the answer! I will look into it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by creating a flag client side, either in core data or NSUserDefaults.

So when the app is upgraded you set flag.  So existing users get all functionality.

For new installs you don't set it until the user makes the in app purchase.

It works nicely with core data because you can use the model upgrade code to initalise the flag.

Note one gotcha is you also need a "restore" button, so the in app purchase can be restored,  otherwise it will be rejected by apple.

Comment: But if the person deletes the app from his/her phone then NSUserDefaults will be cleared up also.

Comment: Yes, they can then use the "Restore" button to re-instate the purchase

Comment: But for my scenario, I have to make sure that only the new customers will be able to purchase the upgrade for the app. All the old customers will get everything!