# User migration issue while making an existing paid app to free and adding In-App-Purchase

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase

I have a existing paid app on iTunes store. I want to make this app free and add In-App-Purchase.

Problem is : Suppose there are two features say A and B, both are available in paid version, now I want to make this app free and add In-App-Purchase on feature B.

I want that existing paid user don't need to pay again for feature B when they update their app, only those users who's installing first time have to In-App-Purchase.
                                                                                           Is there any way to achieve this? (There is no backend system involved in app.)

There is way to achieve this like write some file on iCloud but I believe there may be some bette way to do this.

any help much appreciated!

Comment: Here's a great answer to this question utilizing iOS 7's Receipt Validation Programming Guide: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19391432/2274694

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change paid app to free but know if user previously purchased it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19390810/change-paid-app-to-free-but-know-if-user-previously-purchased-it)