# In-app purchase already Purchased

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, in-app-purchase, development-environment

I want to create an in-app purchase update for my application which it's default version is for purchase already.

I've been wondering, if it is possible for clients who have already paid my application to not pay again. After, the updated version which has an in-app purchase payment.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are providing service which need to purchase only once than you need to create product with Type **"Non consumable"**.

Non consumable product will charge you client only once in the life time. even if you client delete the app and download again and make purchase of the same product. He will never get charge.

As per the Apple review guide line. You also need to put Restore button in you app at some place. This will help you client to restore all Non consumable purchased which he did in the past.

Please refer the link http://www.appcoda.com/in-app-purchase-tutorial/. This gives you detail all type of in app purchased.

Comment: thanks for your answer. yes i know about the non consumable option. but my problem is that my Last Version which is still on appstore is for purchasing. and lots of people has paid for it. and now i want to move the external purchase to an in app purchase.i afraid that the people who have already purchased my app would be forced to pay it again in in app purchase

Comment: That you need to manage with your back end DB. If your client has made external purchase then you no need to show the purchase button. In place of the you will allow user to use the services. in this way you can manage.

Comment: Thanks again. but how could i know that the user has already paid an external purchase. i dont think that there would be such a service provided in xcode or an API Provided by itunes-connect

Comment: I am not getting your point. External purchase means what. How could you client pay externally. does he pay through your website? or anything else.

Comment: sorry i couldnt finde the right word for external purchase. but i think the best word for it would be PrePurchase. which means having to purchase before getting to download it from appstore

Comment: look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19390810/change-paid-app-to-free-but-know-if-user-previously-purchased-it  I think  this is what you are asking for.