# Migrating from paid app to in app purchases iOS

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

Currently i have a paid app, i store no information in `NSUserDefaults` or `keychain` in order to identify that user has paid, and i dont want to release an update just to do that..

Now i want to use `IAP`, and considering the above the only way i can find out if user has already bought the app(version prior to IAP) is through purchase receipt validation, and i would like that to be done locally.

Any ideas how it can be done in swift?

Please don't mark this as duplicate, i have already read other similar posts..

If you can think of any other solution, other than purchase receipt validation, that wouldn't require an interim update please advice..

Comment: did you checked this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19390810/change-paid-app-to-free-but-know-if-user-previously-purchased-it

Comment: yes i have but i dont understand it.. also i need something in swift