# Find out how much user paid for the app

Tags: ios, storekit

Is it possible to use StoreKit to find out how much the user paid for the app, I don't mean In-App-Purchase, the price they paid to download the app.

**Update:**

Is there any solution to make sure the user paid for the app or they are using pirated version?

Comment: I think *"how much"* may not be possible, but *did they pay for* is definitely possible. Here's a very good thread on things that may help you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19390810/change-paid-app-to-free-but-know-if-user-previously-purchased-it - specifically, the first answers along with the comments. (I wanted to attribute two individuals but cannot do both. Read through. Hope it helps.)

Comment: Thanks seem it works. I'll work on it.

Comment: @Maysam You really should redo your question. You don't actually want to know what the user paid for the app. You seem to want to verify they actually paid for it versus loading a crashed version. That's a very different question. And receipt validation is the answer.

Comment: @rmaddy now if you post it as an answer I'll mark it.

Comment: @dfd or if you have any. I've found https://github.com/bizz84/SwiftyStoreKit it, seem does the job.

Answer (score 1):

If they've bought the app from the App Store, they'll have a valid receipt, which you can validate using this guide:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateLocally.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH1-SW2

The receipt can be retrieved by loading the data at this local file path: `[[NSBundle mainBundle] appStoreReceiptURL]`

Answer (score 0):

No, this information is not exposed via StoreKit. I've not came across a way to pull this individual purchase info.

Comment: I wanted to make sure the user is not using a cracked version of the app. An alternative solution would be setting the app price free and use IAP, which is verifiable.