# iOS: restore purchases

Tags: ios, swift

I have several `non-consumable` in-app purchases. But now I want to create new version of app and upload it in app store. In new version I want to remove this `non-consumable` in-app purchases and create instead of them `auto-renewable subscription`. But how users who have already bought `non-consumable`, can restore it after I delete these purchases.

Comment: This is essentially a duplicate of [Change paid app to free but know if user previously purchased it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19390810/change-paid-app-to-free-but-know-if-user-previously-purchased-it). You need to check the receipt and grant access to users who already purchased the old IAP.

Comment: You shouldn't remove the IAPs or remove the code that enables features based on them; simply change your store interface in your app so that new users can no longer purchase them; i.e. those product codes aren't shown.  Existing purchasers will still be able to restore those purchases