# iOS - Restore in app purchase if app itself was already purchased

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase

An iOS app was a initially paid app, then later became free with an in app purchase option.

For a user who has already purchased the app would the `restore` code below, actually restore it? Or does that restore only app specifically to the in app purchase?

If it's only to the in app purchase how can I ensure users who actually paid for the app are also 'restored':

```
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
{

    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions)
    {
        switch (transaction.transactionState)
        {
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
                NSLog(@"Purchased Case");
                [defaultQueue finishTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
                NSLog(@"Failed Case");
                [defaultQueue finishTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
                NSLog(@"Restored Case");
                [defaultQueue restoreCompletedTransactions];
                break;                
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

}
```

And I get the in-app purchased product itself using:

```
- (void) getProductInfo
{
    if ([SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments])
    {
        NSSet *productID = [NSSet setWithObject:@"myoneoffid"];
        SKProductsRequest *request = [[SKProductsRequest alloc]initWithProductIdentifiers:productID];
        request.delegate = self;
        [request start];
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are you asking if, for people who originally purchased the app, you will see a restoration of "myoneoffid" without them having explicitly purchased it?  If so, the answer is no.  They can re-install the app at any time from the app store without charge, but if features are now locked without an IAP, they will get a "locked" app.

Comment: You can use the `original_application_version` field from the receipt to determine the version that was originally purchased by the user.  Note, however, that this actually returns the "build" number, not the version number, so if you reset your build to "1" for each new version, you won't be able to tell what version they actually purchased.  You could release your "free" version with a build number higher than you have ever used before (say 10000) go below that again and then anyone who has original_application_version < 10000 has a paid app.

Comment: There is always a purchase receipt; it just won’t contain any in app purchase fields. You may need to refresh the receipt if it isn’t initially available

Comment: Thanks - however still a little stuck. So I get the receipt using: `NSURL *receiptURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] appStoreReceiptURL];` and then `NSData *receipt = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:receiptURL];`. However looking at `receipt` itself I see no useful info there. It shows `bytes`. I'm expecting to see some useful info that could help determine whether the user paid or not.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't use the "restore purchases" functionality to grant access to users who originally purchased your non-free app prior to adding in-app purchases. Of course you need that functionality in your updated app for newer users that do purchase the in-app purchases.

To handle the case of earlier purchasers of your app, you need to do receipt validation. You can get the receipt and check the original purchase version. If that version is older than whatever version you switched to free with in-app purchases, then you can grant the user access to those features without making them pay for anything.

See [Change paid app to free but know if user previously purchased it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19390810/change-paid-app-to-free-but-know-if-user-previously-purchased-it) for more details.

Comment: Thanks - however still a little stuck. So I get the receipt using: `NSURL *receiptURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] appStoreReceiptURL];` and then `NSData *receipt = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:receiptURL];`. However looking at `receipt` itself I see no useful info there. It shows `bytes`. I'm expecting to see some useful info that could help determine whether the user paid or not.

Comment: In the link I posted here, look at the link in my answer to that question. It shows you how to work with that data.