# iOS - See contents of a receipt

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase

I'm working on handling a scenario, where my app was paid on the app store and now I'm making free to download with in app purchase.
However anyone who has previously purchased I want it to be unlocked for them so they don't pay again.

I have the following code which actually gets the receipt:

```
NSURL *receiptURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] appStoreReceiptURL];
NSData *receipt = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:receiptURL];
if (!receipt) {
    NSLog(@"NO RECP");
} else {
    NSLog(@"GOTACH");
}
```

However looking at that NDData `receipt` its all binary data. How can I actually see whats inside that? I've seen various posts about making requests to some url - do I need to do that? I just want to see whatever in that file (hoping for something like version/bundle id when purchased or even date when first purchased).

And my second question, will that receipt only get the receipt for my app, or does it return all receipts on the device?

Thanks.

Comment: Your code already makes a request to a URL. That how you got the data. And your code just gives the current user's receipt for the app being run.

Comment: As I stated in my answer to [your earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55787736/ios-restore-in-app-purchase-if-app-itself-was-already-purchased), see the [Receipt Validation Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Introduction.html) for details on receipt validation. The code you have so far is barely the first of many steps.