# IAP iOS App. How can I make a paid function only for new users but keep for free for users who already dowloaded paid app?

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

I have my app on App Store for 2.99 but now I want to make it for free and add one paid function inside (IAP for 2.99). Is it possible to keep this function for users who already bought my app on App Store for free after app update? Only new users have available IAP, for previous nothing changed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change paid app to free but know if user previously purchased it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19390810/change-paid-app-to-free-but-know-if-user-previously-purchased-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access to the app version with this code:

```
Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "CFBundleShortVersionString")
```

and enable the feature with logic you want based on the app version and user profile.

Comment: This returns the current version, what he actually needs is the version the app had when the user bought it.